# double ** int function parameter

Tags: function, pointers

Can somebody explain me why does the parameter has double "**"? Like, I know it's the equivalent of the "by reference" in C++, but I need more explanations, please.

```
 int crearevect(int **v)
{
    int nr,i;
    scanf("%d",&nr);
    *v=(int *)(malloc(nr*sizeof(int)));
    for (i=0; i<nr; i++)
        printf("%p ",((*v)+i));
    printf("%p",v);
    return nr;
}
// v[i] = *(v+i)
// *(v)[i] = *(*(v)+i)



void creareMATRICE(int ***a, int *n, int *m)
{
    scanf("%d",n);
    scanf("%d",m);
    *a=(int **)(malloc(*n*sizeof(int)));
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<*n; i++)
        (*a)[i]=(int *)(malloc(*m*sizeof(int)));
    for (i=0; i<*n; i++)
        for (j=0; j<*m; j++)
            scanf("%d",&(*a)[i][j]);
    return;
}
```

Comment: It's a pointer to a pointer. What part are you getting confused about?

Answer (score 0):

- in C refers to pointer. A * refers to a variable that holds memory address, similarly ** refers to a variable that hold memory address of a memory address, likewise *** and so on. You can read more about pointers from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm or any other online reference. But in general you can link a * with variable that can be used to address 1D array (v[i] = *(v+i)), ** with variable that can be used to address 2D array (v[i][j] = *(*(v+i) + j)) and so on.